# A few questions regarding op-amp filters and DC bias

Tags: arduino, operational-amplifier, active-filter

I have a few questions in relation to the attached schematic.....the input signal is a sinusoid of **F=1 Hz** and **Vpeak=2 mV**. The signal passes through a **band pass filter (BPF)** with a **gain of 143**, and then is **DC shifted by 7.5 V**...

My questions are:

1. Why is the input shifted up by **20 mV** after passing through the high pass filter **(see V(n006) in the diagram)**.
2. The capacitor coupled voltage divider bias was able to shift the output signal from the BPF to **7.5 V** as expected, but the signal got highly attenuated **(see V(n003))**. What is the reason behind this and how can I shift **V(n002)** without it being attenuated so much? Is the capacitor and the resistors of the bias circuit playing a part?

[image: Screenshot of schematic]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *Why did the input got shifted up by 20mV after passing through the
> high pass filter*

Because the input bias current of the [LT1215](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/12156fb.pdf) is about 0.5 μA and that current into 47 kΩ produces a DC offset of about 20 mV: -

[image]

> *The capacitor coupled voltage divider bias was able to shift the
> output signal from the BPF to 7.5V as expected, but the signal got
> highly attenuated*

Your signal frequency is 1 Hz and that means the coupling capacitor (C3 = 1 μF) has a reactive impedance of 159 kΩ. This then drops a lot of voltage when considering that the right hand side of that capacitor (C3) has a loading resistance of 10 kΩ || 10 kΩ.

Comment: Will I be alright if I use a higher value capacitor (100uF) and 2.2M Resistor divider? Is Zcap and the parallel combination of the two divider resistors creating another voltage divider network?

Comment: If the DC impedance becomes 1.1 Mohm then there will be an added offset (due to input bias currents) of 0.55 volts. This might not be what you want.

Comment: Simulated the circuit with C=10uF and R=100k and the attenuation was gone. I may be wrong but I think this has something to do with Thevinin's theorem. Thank you so much! To be honest, I never thought about the input bias current thingy. Learnt something new today!!

Comment: Given that your signal is only 1 Hz, you will be much better placed to choose an op-amp with much smaller input offset currents at the expense of bandwidth (that you don't appear to need).

Comment: Actually I will be using LM358/TL072/LM324 to read PPG wave. Arduinos can't read negative voltages so to see the full waveform, I must dc shift the signal. LTspice does not have the aforementioned opamp models so I randomly clicked LT1215 from components list.

Comment: UPDATE: I just did some breadboard stuff and C=10uF, R=100k works fine. The waveform is a wee "capacitory", a bit distorted probably due to the charging and discharging of the coupling capacitor but it will do for now. At least the signal has been DC shifted. Thanks again.